# Access VBA Creating and formatting chart macro works in Excel but not in Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have a module in Access that makes a new Excel spreadsheet, makes a new table, and copies data from the database into the table. I want to create a chart out of this table and format it. The sub to create the chart is below.

```
    Dim xlapp as Excel.Application
    Dim wb as Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws as Excel.Worksheet
    Set xlapp = New Excel.Application
    Set wb = 'created new workbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

    ws.Range("Results_Table[#All]").Select
    ws.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Results_Table[#All]")

    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 1
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 1
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).AxisGroup = 1
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).AxisGroup = 1
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(5).ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(5).AxisGroup = 1
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(6).ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(6).AxisGroup = 1
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(7).ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(7).AxisGroup = 1
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(8).ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(8).AxisGroup = 2
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(9).ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(9).AxisGroup = 2
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(10).ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(10).AxisGroup = 2
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(11).ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(11).AxisGroup = 2
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(12).ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(12).AxisGroup = 2
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(13).ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(13).AxisGroup = 2
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(14).ChartType = xlXYScatter
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(14).AxisGroup = 2

    ActiveChart.ChartGroups(2).Overlap = 100
    ActiveChart.ChartGroups(2).GapWidth = 475

    ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 159
```

In access, this code can successfully create a chart of the 'Column Clustered' type. However, that's all. Everything below where I attempt to change some parts into stacked columns or scatters does nothing. I can put a print statement at the bottom of it all that registers, so I know the code actually reaches that point.

I can also copy and paste this exact code (changing `ws` to `ActiveSheet`) and it works perfect, creating the chart I want and formatting it exactly as it is supposed to.

I am unsure why these commands work in Excel but not in the Access module.

Comment: Please show the `Dim` lines of sub so we can see your Excel objects.

Comment: Also, I wonder about your error handling as you might have an `On Error Resume Next` suppressing informative errors. Please post a fuller code example for us to help.

Comment: @Parfait This is the entire sub, I don't have any error handling here because I like using the debugger to point to problem lines. I use global variables (bad practice, I know...) but I will include the Dim and Set statements at the top.

Comment: Please post even the Public Sub/Function lines. I cannot see how `ActiveChart` is recognized by Access. Are you sure this is in an MS Access standalone module or run inside Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, your issue is accessing Excel objects outside of Excel. In MS Office applications when you do not qualify methods with a named object, it is assumed you are accessing objects within the host application. See below illustration with the workbook object

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application          ' UNNECESSARY IF INSIDE MS EXCEL

Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(...)      ' ASSIGN EXCEL WORKBOOK EXTERNALLY

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(...)            ' ASSIGN EXCEL WORKBOOK INTERNALLY
```

Hence, your `ActiveChart` is pointing to an MS Access `ActiveChart` object which may be its OLEDB Chart form/report object or your code *is* error-ing out but you are suppressing message (i.e., `On Error Resume Next`) as this does not sound like an MS Access object.

But to access Excel's *Chart* object, assign it to a defined object with `Set` operator:

```
Dim myChart As Object                 ' LATE BINDING 
'Dim myChart As Excel.Chart           ' EARLY BINDING
...

ws.Range("Results_Table[#All]").Select

Set myChart = ws.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered)
myChart.SetSourceData Source:=ws.Range("Results_Table[#All]")

myChart.Select
myChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlColumnStacked
myChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 1
...
```

Alternatively use the `With...End With` block and a DRY-er code with a loop

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim i As Integer
...

ws.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select

With xlApp.ActiveChart
    .SetSourceData Source:=ws.Range("Results_Table[#All]")

    For i = 1 To 14
       .FullSeriesCollection(i).ChartType = xlColumnStacked
       .FullSeriesCollection(i).AxisGroup = 1
    Next i

    ...

End With
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Parfait. I attempted to set myChart as an object, but an error is thrown on the first .fullSeriesCollection line saying 'Object does not support this property'

Comment: Also worth pointing out that if you're using _late binding_ Access won't have a clue what `xlColumnClustered` or `xlColumnStacked` means.  They'll need replacing with their numerical equivalents - 51 & 52.  To find the numbers just type `?xlColumnStacked` into Excels immediate window.

Comment: I missed the `.SetSourceData` line. Try again.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the active chart is not the chart you just created? Try something like:

```
dim chrt as Chart
set chrt = ws.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered)
chrt.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Results_Table[#All]")
```

replacing active chart with chrt.

Comment: yes, most likely access thinks `ActiveChart` is the active chart in the access application itself and the object needs to be tied explicitly to the excel chart.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, declaring `chrt` as a `Chart` gives a type mismatch. I tried to declare it as an `Excel.Chart`, but this also results in a type mismatch. I had assumed that since I have the `.Select` line right beforehand, the activeChart would be the one I just selected. Anyways, the `.SetSourceData` line works with the ActiveChart

Comment: OK fair enough, I must confess to being completely unfamiliar with the Access object model.  It does seem like those objects are not supported.  Also, did you try 
'dim chrt as Graph.Chart' ?